# How do I use the outputs from the network module in the security group module without creating resources twice?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-modules

```
├── instance.tf
├── module
│   ├── Network
│   │   ├── output.tf
│   │   ├── resource.tf
│   │   └── vars.tf
│   └── sg
│       ├── output.tf
│       └── resource.tf
├── provider.tf
├── terraform.tfstate
├── terraform.tfstate.backup
└── vars.tf
```

This is my project folder structure

I am trying to create two modules, one is for vpc and another one for security  group . Here is my outputs for vpc module

```
output "vpc_id" {
    value = aws_vpc.vpc_dev.id
}
output "public_subnet_id" {
    value = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id 
}
output "private_subnet_id" {
    value = aws_subnet.private_subnet.id
}
```

the security groups module looks like

```
module "NetworkModule" {
    source ="../Network"
}
resource "aws_security_group" "sg_dev" {
    name = "web_sg"
    vpc_id = module.NetworkModule.vpc_id
    ....
    ...}
```

here is the outputs for sg module

```
output "sg_id" {
    value = aws_security_group.sg_dev.id
}
```

i am using this modules to create my instance in aws

```
module "NetworkModule" {
    source = "./module/Network"
}
module "sgmodule"{
    source = "./module/sg"
}
resource "aws_instance" "web_dev" {
    ami = var.AMIS[var.REGION]
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    subnet_id = module.NetworkModule.public_subnet_id
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${module.sgmodule.sg_id}"]
    tags = {
        Name = "web_dev"
    }
}
```

But  i can see everything related to  vpc module is getting created for two times (for eg. i can see two vpc instead of one , 2 public subnets instead of one  etc.)  ..am i using the modules in the right way ? ..

How do I use the outputs from the network module in the security group module without creating resources twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In instance.tf you have:

```
module "NetworkModule" {
    source = "./module/Network"
}
module "sgmodule"{
    source = "./module/sg"
}
```

In module/sg/resource.tf you have:

```
module "NetworkModule" {
    source ="../Network"
}
```

As a result you get two instances of the Network module, and double the resources.

Using **module** in Terraform is somewhat like using **new** in other languages. It instantiates the module again, creating another copy of its required resources. This is generally useful, but it's suprising in your case.

What you should likely do is remove the **NetworkModule** module from module/sg/resource.tf and replace it with a variable:

```
variable "vpc_id" {
    type = string
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg_dev" {
    name = "web_sg"
    vpc_id = var.vpc_id
    ....
    ...}
```

Then in instance.tf provide that variable to the **sgmodule** module block:

```
module "sgmodule"{
    source = "./module/sg"
    vpc_id = module.NetworkModule.vpc_id
}
```

Now you'll have the dependencies you need without the duplication of network infrastructure resources.